# Can't start container through JDBC url with Spring boot (No XA DataSource class name specified)

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

I'm trying to run testContainer with specified url in app.yml:

```
   datasource:
      driver-сlass-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
      url: jdbc:tc:postgresql://hostname/databasename
      username: user
      password: password
```

but always get exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No XA DataSource class name specified
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 51 more 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No XA DataSource class name specified
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No XA DataSource class name specified
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.createXaDataSource(XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:88)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 65 more
```

If I do the same things manually in the bean everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No XA DataSource class name specified`

The `XADataSourceAutoConfiguration` is conditional on `XADataSourceWrapper`.
See [github src](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.java)

```
@ConditionalOnBean(XADataSourceWrapper.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(DataSource.class)
public class XADataSourceAutoConfiguration implements BeanClassLoaderAware {
```

Check where the XA configuration comes form.
Usually the candidates are `Narayana`, `Bitronix` or `Atomikos` jta providers.